# How to be able to input two different numbers in two different lines

Tags: java

As an exercise, I need to write a code that can input two different numbers in two different lines

For example:

```
Input:      82
            85
```

I have tried this but it didn't work out:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String X = scan.nextLine().trim();
```

Please help

Comment: scan.nextInt() ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 scanners like this:

```
Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Or you can input 82,85 (comma separated) and then take scan[0] and scan[1]